# Reading Image after writing

Tags: android, android-camera

I have written some Android code were I basically only take a picture with the built in camera, save it, and then try to load the saved file to do some stuff with it.

```
Camera camera = mPreview.getmCameraInstance();
Camera.PictureCallback pictureCallback =
    GetPictureCallback(mPreview.getmCameraInstance());
camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCallback);
Mat image = Highgui.imread(String.valueOf(file)); //Load Image here
```

However, my application crashes because it will not find a file in the line where i load my image. I do not understand this, because I thought that my code would execute in a sequential manner, and then the `takePicture(...)` in which I store my file would already be done.

Can you help me with this?

**EDIT**

When I put a `Thread.sleep(100)` before, I can open the image, as it has been successfully written at that time.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Can you tell me a solution how I can wait for my file-writing to be done?

Comment: Its no different than for a onClickListener for a Button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait until your callback has been called in order to read the image.

What is `GetPictureCallback`?  If it's your own code, then move the image reading into the generated callback... if not, the you can do something like this:

```
Camera camera = mPreview.getmCameraInstance();
final Camera.PictureCallback otherPictureCallback =
    GetPictureCallback(mPreview.getmCameraInstance());
camera.takePicture(null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback {
    void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        otherPictureCallback.onPictureTaken(data, camera);
        Mat image = Highgui.imread(String.valueOf(file)); //Load Image here     
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a good idea! I assume there is no such way of "waiting" for a callback to be done like waiting for a thread with `.join()`?

Comment: Not an automatic way.